# MainWindowViewModel ref to User Control ViewModel instances

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MainWindow with the DataContext set to its MainWindowViewModel.cs class.
Inside the MainWindow I have 2 user controls and each user control is bound to it`s corresponding ViewModel (e.g UserControl1ViewModel.cs and UserControl2ViewModel.cs).

How can I get a reference to the User`s Control ViewModel from the MainWindowViewModel.cs so I can manipulate their data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic approach is as below

Instantiate the DataContext of the child user controls when you instantiate the DataContext of parent
example

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        <uc:UC1 DataContext="{Binding Uc1Vm}"/>
        <uc:UC2 DataContext="{Binding Uc2Vm}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Below is the Main viewmodel

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            //Below would be replaced by an IOC container instatiation in real world(Unity, MEF etc..)
            Uc1Vm = new UC1ViewModel(),
            Uc2Vm = new UC2ViewModel()
        };
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel can be composed of the 2 child view models as below

```
public UC1ViewModel Uc1Vm { get; set; }

public UC2ViewModel Uc2Vm { get; set; }
```

You can manipulate the child controls as below for example from MainWindowViewModel

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Text is in MainWindowViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public string Text 
    {
        get { return _text;}
        set
        {
            if(value !=_text)
            {
                _text = value;
                //User control1 has Text property in its view model
                Uc1Vm.Text = _text;
                //User control2 has Content property in its view model
                Uc2Vm.Content = _text;
                if(PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps or you have any query.

Comment: So the way to get the reference to the controls is to instantiate them in the MainViewModel.cs. There s no other way to get a hold of those from the MainWindowVM.cs when they re directly passed the controls directly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by passing them directly? If you paste a sample code then I can relate it more